# Realm notification never called after initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a UIView where i want to update my ui after i received and parse the json from the backend.
I use a generic API manager so my callback is called too soon.
My workaround and the best practice i think would be to use a realm notification block.
The notification block is called once on viewDidLoad but the update is not called even though i modify a realm object property after the parsing of the json.
Sample of code for the view :

```
import SwiftyJson
import RealmSwift

var notificationToken: NotificationToken?
var article: Article?

        if let result = Article.getLocalArticle(article!.id) {
            // Observe Notifications on article from Network
            notificationToken = result.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
                switch changes {
                case .Initial:
                    break
                case .Update:
                    print("updating")
                    self!.updateView()
                case .Error(let error):
                    // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                    fatalError("\(error)")
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

Sample for the realm object :

```
import SwiftyJson
import RealmSwift

public class Article : Object {
  dynamic var liked = false
  dynamic var id = String()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
    }
    // MARK: – Create article method

public class func article(json: JSON) -> Article? {

    let article = Article()

    if let id = json["id"].string {
        article.id = id
    }
    if let liked = json["liked"].bool {
        article.liked = liked
    }
    return article
}
  // parse response Json for only one article after getting articleDetail
  public class func parseUpdateArticleJson(json: JSON) {
      //print(json)

      do {
          let realm = try Realm()
          realm.beginWrite()
          let article = self.article(json)
          realm.add(article!, update: true)
          try realm.commitWrite()

      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
    }


  public class func getLocalArticle(articleId: String) -> Results<Article>? {
      do {
          let realm = try Realm()
          let result = realm.objects(Article.self).filter("id == %@", articleId)
          return result
      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
      return nil
    }
 }
```

After a tap on the like button in my view i send the action to the backend which will update my realm object setting the liked property to true (or false if it was true).
The expected behaviour is for the notification block to call the updateView method when the like property on my realm object is updated.
Any hint would be welcome

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell without knowing more about whats going on. But first I would check to see if your Realm notification is actually getting set. Is your code to parse JSON from the backend updating the same Realm object from `Article.getLocalArticle(article!.id)`? Are you also writing your updates to the realm object by wrapping your code in a `realm.write` block or committing the write by using `realm.commitWrite()`?

Comment: I updated my sample.
The answer is yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the issue is how you're adding the object to Realm. You can only set `update` to true in `realm.add(article!, update: true)` when a primary key exists. The update property tells realm to intelligently update the Realm object based on it's primary key (or just add it if it doesn't exist).

Check this out for more info: 
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#creating-and-updating-objects-with-primary-keys

---

The reason it's failing is because Realm throws an exception when you are doing `realm.add(article!, update:true)` with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Article' does not have a primary key and can not be updated'
```

And your do/catch block catches the error. The object never gets added to realm and the notification block never gets notified. That's my assumption right now as to why it's failing. However, I see that you are printing out the error so maybe you caught this already.

---

So what you can do is assign a primary key to your Article object by doing this:

```
public class Article : Object {
    dynamic var liked = false
    dynamic var id = String()

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

Or if you don't want your `id` property to be a primary key (i.e. unique) then you can add the object by doing this: `realm.add(article)`. The default value of update will be false. Which means it will always add (and never update), even if an object exists with the same primary key.

Comment: I didn't add the primaryKey method because i thought it was obvious i had one, i updated the sample with the primaryKey method in my code which is the exact same one you put in your answer.


That's why i put the id var on my sample, i have more than 15 variables in my model, and since it is company code i cannot put everything i want on SO, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: No worries, that's understandable. It wasn't obvious to me :) Hmm I just tested a version of your code on my machine and Realm notifications are working for me. Can you check to see if your `id` is getting parsed properly in `article(json: JSON)` and make sure this is returning the right results: `Article.getLocalArticle(article!.id)` (after you add the article).

Comment: If that's not it, I wonder if it has something to do with how Realm handles threads. But I didn't expect that to be a problem since all Realm instances across threads should be synced/refreshed on every write or iteration of the run loop.

Comment: Well, thanks to you i found the culprit.
It was a misunderstanding between the ios team and the backend team, the backend didn't send back expected values. 
My bad, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, glad you found the issue!

Comment: Glad you two sorted this out!